Cant get spotipy to play without browser
I've been trying to get this thing going with just previews, but when i use the button nothing happens, no error, nothing
device = self.sp.devices()
        for device in device['devices']:
            if device['name'] == 'HERP':
                device_id = device['id']
        device = device_id
        play_button = ttk.Button(
            self.player_window,
            text="play",
            style="TButton",
            command=lambda:self.sp.start_playback(
            uris=musica_id,
            device_id=id_device)
        )
        play_button.pack(pady=(20, 10), ipadx=20, ipady=5)

I had the "premium required" problem, i changed to OAuth2.0 and fixed it, then i had permissions problems, added scope user read playback and fixed it, then i had "Device not found, reason: None" and i wrote that loop that searches for the spotify device im currently using, now i get the error "URIs must be a list" i already tried making device a list
as
device = (device_id,None)
as
uris=(musica_id,None) 
and also as
uri=([])
uri.append(id_device)

i really cant get this to work, ive tried pygame,spotipy,vlc and nothing seems to play the audio.
thanks in advance for the help
